# Отправка tcp пакета на сервер

Tags: java, android, сокет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть код который отправляет tcp пакет на сервер, но он отправляет только один раз, а после просто молчит. Нужно чтобы клиент мог отправлять tcp пакеты непрерывно и без реконекта.

```
socket = new Socket("192.168.0.2", 80);
Log.e("лог", "Соединение установлено");
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
String str = "hi";
byte buf[] = str.getBytes();
out.write(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если ответить на ваш вопрос коротко, то поместите в цикл эту часть кода:

```
while (true) {
  String str = "hi";
  byte buf[] = str.getBytes();
  out.write(buf);
  out.flush();
}
```

только вы получите "заблокированный" thread и нагрузку на проц 100%.

Comment: Нет, нужно чтобы можно было многократно писать. Просто получается, что один раз напишешь, а дальше телефон просто молчит.

Answer (score 0):

Вы очень не понятно задаете вопрос.
Что будет у вас источником ввода текста? И что за телефон молчит?
Вот, для тестов, можно использовать код:

```
    Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.2", 80);
    Log.e("лог", "Соединение установлено");
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.print("Hello. Please write your name: ");
    try {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Your name is: " + line);
            byte buf[] = line.getBytes();
            out.write(buf);
            out.flush();
            System.out.print("Hello. Please write your name: ");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

это позволит вам из консоли вводить текст, который отобразится у вас в консоли и отправится в сокет.